# Stack Overflow Error when Running ASP.NET Core 6 Backend as .exe Outside IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, backend, .net-6.0

I have encountered a perplexing issue with my ASP.NET Core 6 backend application. When I run it within the Visual Studio IDE, everything works perfectly. However, if I create a build and attempt to run the program through the generated .exe file, it suddenly throws a stack overflow error after approximately 1 minute of execution. I'm struggling to understand why this issue occurs only when running the program as an .exe file and not within the IDE.

- I have verified that I am using the exact same build in my IDE and the .exe file; it is 100% the same source code.
- I attempted to debug the working code to see if it's possible for a stack overflow to occur through user interaction with the backend. However, it seems irrelevant whether I interact extensively with the backend or do nothing at all; the error occurs almost instantly after the program is started."

Comment: maybe you provide some command-line-args to your program in IDE, while not in the other case? How should we guess without any code?

Comment: I haven't configured any custom command-line arguments in my project. While it's possible that Visual Studio Code might automatically include some arguments without my intervention, I haven't come across any information on this topic online yet.
And I don't think that code would help that much. I mean, my backend works perfectly fine, and I don't see a lot of value in putting 1000+ lines of code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might find an error entry with a stack trace in the Event Log.

Comment: Try Enable detailed logging in your application to get more information about the error. This can help identify the specific code that is causing the stack overflow.
If possible, try running the .exe file on a different machine or environment to see if the issue persists. This can help determine if the problem is specific to your development environment or if it's a more general issue.The application might rely on certain environment variables that are set within the IDE but not available when running the .exe file. Make sure that any required environment variables are properly set with exe.